# Changing DropDownListFor Style

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4

Been trying several ways to change the style of a DropDownListFor element.  Either I am doing something wrong or there is something overriding it.. I've tried changing it in the view element and in the CSS.. and no go.

View:

```
<div style="width: 100%; ">
    <div style="float: left;"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FranPID, new SelectList(Model.FranchiseList, "FranchiseID", "FranBusinessName", new { @class = "selectStyle" }))</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.selectStyle {
    border: 1px solid #93A9C8;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #444;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

**EDIT Solved:**

Correct Call:

```
<div style="width: 100%; ">
    <div style="float: left;"> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FranPID, new SelectList(Model.FranchiseList, "FranchiseID", "FranBusinessName"), new { @class = "selectStyle" })</div>
</div>
```

Badsically I had the new inside the SelectList call.. moving it out (changing the parans) and all is working

Comment: Looks good to me.  If you right click and inspect the element do you see your styles listed?

Comment: No.. it has a few different settings and states "Inherited From Body" as though that inheritance has precedence over my CSS entry?  Let me located the inheritance in the CSS.

Comment: Well the inline style is blank.  Assuming this is where the CSS elements should be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is one way...I'd like others to show me if there's a better way because I need to learn more!

in the view:

```
    <div id="products" class="container" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-5 col-sm-4 dropdownlist">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedCategoryId)
                @Html.DropDownList("id", Model.CategoryItems, new { @id = "ddlCategories", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and in the css:

```
/* the width of the entire in div of id=product */
#products {
    width: 100%;
}
/* any item in the div of id=product with its class having dropdownlist */
#products .dropdownlist{
    font-size: 18px;
}
/* any dropdown in product id div */
#products select{
    color: blue;
}
/* specifically, any item with id of ddlCategories in the div of id=product */
#products #ddlCategories
{
    color: red;
}
```

Hope this helps.